# Keeping files updated with a Chef recipe

Tags: ruby, synchronization, chef-infra, auto-update

[image: challenge prompt]

The challenge prompt is above, and my latest attempt is below. The directories and files are created as expected, and the read-out after executing `chef-apply multipleCopies.rb` tells me the files are linked, but when I update any one of the files, the others do not follow suit. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
for x in 1..3
    directory "multipleCopy#{x}" do
        mode '0755'
        action :create
    end
end
file "multipleCopy1/secret.txt" do
        mode '0755'
        action :create
end
for x in 2..3
    link "multipleCopy#{x}/secret.txt" do
        to "multipleCopy1/secret.txt"
        link_type :hard
        subscribes :reload, "multipleCopy1/secret.txt", :immediately
    end
end
```

Note: For less headache, I am testing the recipe locally before uploading to the `ubuntu` server referenced in the prompt, which is why my file paths are different and why I have not yet included the ownership properties.

Comment: This mentioned grading, are you sure it's kosher to be asking for help on here?

Comment: @coderanger It’s not ‘Grading’ in an academic sense, though I appreciate your consideration to the laws of kosher. That part of the spec is to show how the program is to be run and tested. That being said, might you have any questions/suggestions in the way of helping shine a light on a potential solution?

Answer (score 1):

So a file hard link doesn't seem to be what the question is going for (though I would say your solution is maybe better since this is really not what Chef is for, more on that later). Instead they seem to want you to have three actually different files, but sync the contents.

So first the easy parts, creating the directories and the empty initial files. It's rare to see those `for` loops used in Ruby code, though it is syntactically valid:

```
3.times do |n|
  directory "/var/save/multipleCopy#{n+1}" do
    owner "ubuntu"
    group "root"
    mode "755"
  end

  file "/var/save/multipleCopy#{n+1}/secret.txt" do
    owner "root
    group "root"
    mode "755"
  end
end
```

But that doesn't implement the hard part of sync'ing the files. For that we need to first analyze the mtimes on the files and use the most recent as the file content to set.

```
latest_file = 3.times.sort_by { |n| ::File.mtime("/var/save/multipleCopy#{n+1}/secret.txt") rescue 0 }
latest_content = ::File.read("/var/save/multipleCopy#{latest_file+1}/secret.txt") rescue nil
```

and then in the file resource:

```
  file "/var/save/multipleCopy#{n+1}/secret.txt" do
    owner "root
    group "root"
    mode "755"
    content latest_content
  end
```

As for this not being a good use of Chef: Chef is about writing code which asserts the desired state of the machine. In the case of files like this, rather than doing this kind of funky stuff to check if a file has been edited, you would just say that Chef owns the file content for all three and if you want to update it, you do it via your cookbook (and then usually use a `template` or `cookbook_file` resource).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and informative response, coderanger! Glad to know I'm not the only one that thinks this use case is a bit odd. Anyway, I first attempted splicing my original code with your suggestions but to no avail, so I tried using your full response instead (file paths and ownership aside) but am still not making any improvements. The text files neither update automatically nor after re-running `chef-apply multipleCopies.rb`. Is this how you meant for it to be implemented? https://gist.github.com/nckgrzn/3f1e3b8fdbf3d65fd9dc1294f71c46ed

Comment: 1. you removed the file ownership management and the paths no longer match 2. no it would all be as one pass.

Comment: 1. I removed file ownership because I'm testing the recipe for correctness locally before passing it to the `ubuntu` server referenced. And the paths DO match, or are you seeing something I'm not? 2. Not sure what you mean by 'one pass', but in regards to the other difference between your suggestion and my gist as well as what I suspect you might mean--a) I added the loop to your third portion of code because `n` is not assigned without it, b) and I cannot replace the `file` resource in the first portion with the third portion nor delete it or other vars will be called before assignment.

Comment: So I tweaked your `latest_file` line to return the single number of the most recently updated file instead of the array `[0,1,2]` (assuming that was your original intention) and re-spliced it into a new take on my original code where I hard-link the other files to the updated one, and it works! Well, after re-running the file execution command it works, though I get the sense they want the files to update automatically... Any further thoughts on that aspect of it? Thanks in advance. Here's my latest code: https://gist.github.com/nckgrzn/6e0064c6a6a475ab95ef5f4908b9fc03